# How can I determine that LAN cable is not connected to the Samsung TV (Model: QE55Q6FNA) (Tizen 3.6)

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I build application for the **Samsung TV** in JavaScript using `webapis.js`, now I have an issue to determine when **LAN** cable is attached/detached. My TV is connected to the internet via switch. When I detach internet cable from the switch I can determine that via `webapis.network.isConnectedToGateway();` but when I detach **LAN** cable from the switch my application on the TV is stuck, developer tools throws an error: "*Debugging connection was closed Reason: Websocket disconnected*", so I can't even debug this case. I've already tried to save logs in `cookies`/`LocalStorage` but they are removed as soon as developer tools is disconnected.

So, how can I determine that LAN cable is not connected to the TV. 
Note: I don’t need to know when GATEWAY_DISCONNECTED but rather when [LAN_CABLE_DETACHED](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/network-api).

Here is what I've tried so far:

```js
function getIsConnected () {
        try {
            /// This will throw an exception when LAN is disconnected
            var isConnectedToGateway = webapis.network.isConnectedToGateway();

            console.log("isCableConnected value :: " + isConnectedToGateway);

            return isConnectedToGateway;

             /// won't help me here as when LAN is detached that doesn't work
            //return Device.getNetworkConnectionType() === "LAN";
        } catch (e) {
            log.info("isCableConnected error :: " + e.message);
            return 0;
        }
    }


/// I've also tried this, without any succes
webapis.network.getActiveConnectionType();

/// It only determines 2 states: GATEWAY_CONNECTED = 4; & GATEWAY_DISCONNECTED = 5;
/// which is not what I need 
webapis.network.addNetworkStateChangeListener(function (data) {
     if (data === 2) { // LAN_CABLE_DETACHED
       // never gets here
     } else if (data === 1) { // LAN_CABLE_ATTACHED
      // never gets here either
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you using [Systeminfo Public Web API](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/tizen/systeminfo.html#SystemInfoEthernetNetwork) for your purpose.

You can use:

```js
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("ETHERNET_NETWORK", (s) => {console.log(s)}, (e) => {console.log(e)})
```

to determine if network cable is connected.

You can add a listener for notifications about this status changes with:

```js
tizen.systeminfo.addPropertyValueChangeListener("ETHERNET_NETWORK", (s) => {console.log(s)})
```

and you will then receive events when cable connected/disconnnected.

EDIT:
You can use public Web API to determine if network is in one of two states:

- network cable is connected to TV, but network switch has no internet access (*cable* value is **"ATTACHED"**):

```js
> tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("ETHERNET_NETWORK", (s) => {console.log(s)}, (e) => {console.log(e)})
SystemInfoEthernetNetwork {cable: "ATTACHED", status: "DISCONNECTED", ipAddress: "", ipv6Address: "", macAddress: "ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef", …}
```

- network cable is not connected to TV (*cable* value is **"DETACHED"**):

```js
> tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("ETHERNET_NETWORK", (s) => {console.log(s)}, (e) => {console.log(e)})

SystemInfoEthernetNetwork {cable: "DETACHED", status: "DEACTIVATED", ipAddress: "", ipv6Address: "", macAddress: "ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef", …}
```

It is not supported in Web API to register listener on physical layer, as mentioned in [docs](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/tizen/systeminfo.html#SystemInfoEthernetNetwork): *"Change listener registered on ETHERNET_NETWORK property is triggered on ipAddress and ipv6Address properties change (the network layer)."*

Comment: By saying **cable** do you mean `LAN` or just Internet cable from the switch to the wall? I intentionally mentioned, in my question, that I'm able to determine when `GATEWAY_DISCONNECTED` is fired, that is when cable from the wall is disconnected. What I can't determine is when `LAN` cable is detached from the TV.

Comment: @Krusader I edited my answer to explain how Web API partially supports your scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I detach Internet cable from the switch `getPropertyValue("ETHERNET_NETWORK"` fires with the following values: `cable: "ATTACHED"` & `status: "CONNECTED"`